# mouseenter event does not working for gwt celltable

Tags: gwt, mouseevent, mouseover, mouseenter, gwt-celltable

I have one celltable and I need to add handler on its row for "mouseenter" event.

I have tried something like following, but its not working for "mouseenter" althought it works for "mouseover".

```
cellTable.addCellPreviewHandler(new CellPreviewEvent.Handler<Test>(){
        @Override
        public void onCellPreview(CellPreviewEvent<Test> event) {
            if ("mouseenter".equals(event.getNativeEvent().getType())){
                Window.alert("mouse entered");
            }
        }       
    });
```

Comment: What browser you're using? [This](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/) says that Chrome doesn't fire it.

Comment: Exactly, I am using chrome.

Answer (score 0):

Is not working properly for mouseenter events because apparently is only implemented by IE and Opera, since you're Chrome, you can just wait until they implement it.

> Unfortunately Firefox, Chrome, and Safari still haven’t copied this brilliant Microsoft invention, that has even made it to the spec. Come on, guys!

From this [source](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/mouseover.html).